# Create QTreeWidget directories based on file paths/names?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qstring, qtreewidget

In my project, I have a QVector full of QStrings containing file paths/names that don't actually exist on any drive:

```
QVector<QString> fileNames["level.dat", "data/villages.dat", "players/player1.dat"]//etc
```

I want to create a tree in my QTreeWidget that resembles a sort of file directory like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIzlp.png]

How would I go about creating something like this quickly and efficiently?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution does not avoid duplicate, so if you need that in the future, you could extend this piece of code with adding valiation for that. Anyway, this code produces the exact ame output for me that you have just described to wish to have.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QStringList fileNames{"level.dat", "data/villages.dat", "players/player1.dat"};
    QTreeWidget treeWidget;
    treeWidget.setColumnCount(1);

    for (const auto& filename : fileNames) {
        QTreeWidgetItem *parentTreeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(&treeWidget);
        parentTreeItem->setText(0, filename.split('/').first());
        QStringList filenameParts = filename.split('/').mid(1);
        for (const auto& filenamePart : filenameParts) {
            QTreeWidgetItem *treeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
            treeItem->setText(0, filenamePart);
            parentTreeItem->addChild(treeItem);
            parentTreeItem = treeItem;
        }
    }

    treeWidget.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++14
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

On a site node: you ought to use QStringList rather than QVector. In addition, your current initialization attempt surely results in compiler error. That is invalid initialization.

Comment: Thanks. I have since switched to a QStringList. The initialization included in the question I wrote is not how I actually initialize fileName.

I'm getting lot's of syntax errors:

146: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'

Comment: I have fixed the syntax problems, had to do with C++11. Yeah looks like I'll have to add checks for duplication. Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't mind, how would you go about checking for duplicates?